Por que no se ejecuta la consulta?
estoy intentando hacer una consulta, pero por algún motivo la conexión no se abre o no se pasa a la variable conn, pongo el código a continuación.
Clase conexión
class Data
{
companion object
{
    private const val  JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mssql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private const val DB_URL = "jdbc:mssql//";
    private const val USER = "sa";
    private const val  PASSWORD = "";

    init
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        }
        catch (ex: ClassNotFoundException)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun getConnection(): Connection?
    {
        var conn: Connection? = null;
        try
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        }
        catch (ex: SQLException)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun closeConnection(conn: Connection?)
    {
        try
        {
            conn?.close();
        }
        catch (ex: SQLException)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
Clase modelo
fun getFolio(): Int
{
    var folio = 0;
    val query = "{Call stp_Parametros_getFolioM}";
    var conn: Connection? = null;
    var cs: CallableStatement? = null;
    var rs: ResultSet? = null;

    try
    {
        conn = Data.getConnection();
        cs = conn?.prepareCall(query);
        rs = cs?.executeQuery();

        while (rs?.next() == true)
        {
            folio = rs.getInt("FolioTicket");
        }
    }
    catch (ex: SQLException)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        rs?.close();
        cs?.close();
        Data.closeConnection(conn);
    }

    return folio;
}

Ya debuggee, vi que la variable conn no recibe los datos de Clase conexión.

No estoy seguro de que esto funcione y aunque lo haga, sería de un altísimo riesgo exponer de esta manera la base de datos. Este tipo de acciones suelen hacerse mediante un Web Service, usando Retrofit, Volley u otra librería específica para comunicaciones cliente/servidor.

¿Has revisado bien la ruta de conexión de tu jdbc?
En tu clase Data, tienes definida la URL de conexión de la siguiente manera:
private const val DB_URL = "jdbc:mssql//";

La URL debe estar completa y formateada para conectarte e incluir detalles como el host, el puerto, y el nombre específico de la base de datos.
Prueba:
private const val DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName-tuBasedeDatosM;";


Hola, buenas, si en el proyecto si lo tengo asi, solo aqui no lo puse porque la direccion es una IP

Si usas mssql, la url de conexión debe ser:
jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=<database>.

realiza el cambio adecuado, definiendo tu servidor, puero y base de datos:
private const val  JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mssql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
private const val DB_URL = jdbc:sqlserver://<servidor>:<puerto>;databaseName=<basededatos>

